# TKINTER: Read file if entries match stored data?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to python, I am trying to create a button function that can both write new data to file and if written data matches then fetch load the data from profile.

The issue I face is here:

line 12: if firstname_info in list_of_files:

code does not run the if statement of the loop - maybe I have made an error with the variable matching the file?

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import os

def register_user():
    firstname_info = firstname.get()
    lastname_info = lastname.get()
    iden_info = iden.get()
    email_info = email.get()

    list_of_files = os.listdir()

    if firstname_info in list_of_files:
        file1 = open(firstname_info, "r")
        verify = file1.read().splitlines()
        if lastname_info in verify:
            if iden_info in verify:
                if email_info in verify:
                    print("it worked")
        else:
            print("user not found")

def main_screen():
    global screen
    screen = Tk()

    global firstname
    global lastname
    global iden
    global email

    firstname = StringVar()
    lastname = StringVar()
    iden = StringVar()
    email = StringVar()

    header = Label(text = "Header")
    firstname_label = Label(text = "Firstname")
    lastname_label = Label(text = "lastname")
    iden_label = Label(text = "Student ID")
    email_label = Label(text = "Student Email")

    header.grid(row=0, column=1)
    firstname_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
    lastname_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
    iden_label.grid(row=3, column=0)
    email_label.grid(row=4, column=0)

    b1 = Button(text = "Submit", command = register_user)
    b1.grid(row = 5, column = 1)

    global firstname_entry
    global lastname_entry
    global iden_entry
    global email_entry

    firstname_entry = Entry(textvariable = firstname)
    firstname_entry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    lastname_entry = Entry(textvariable = lastname)
    lastname_entry.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    iden_entry = Entry(textvariable = iden)
    iden_entry.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
    email_entry = Entry(textvariable = email)
    email_entry.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

    screen.mainloop()

main_screen()
```

thanks

Comment: Can you please be more specific about your problem and the part of your code that need to be reconsidered?

Comment: @MohamadArmoon updated, hope it's clearer, sorry new to python so explanations may be a little off, thanks.

Comment: did you specify a path in `os.listdir()`? By default it will only list the files in your python path.

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you tried printing out what is in `list_of_files` and what is in `firstname_info`, to make sure they are what you're assuming they are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your script in the same directory of the `stored data`, it should work as `os.listdir()` will search file in `.` directory which is current directory.  However, it is better to specify the directory of the `stored data` in `os.listdir()`, like `os.listdir('/path/to/stored/data')`.  Also, I think the following block of code:

```
if firstname_info in list_of_files:
    file1 = open(firstname_info, "r")
    verify = file1.read().splitlines()
    if lastname_info in verify:
        if iden_info in verify:
            if email_info in verify:
                print("it worked")
    else:
        print("user not found")
```

should be changed to:

```
if firstname_info in list_of_files:
    print('user profile found')
    with open(firstname_info, "r") as file1:
        verify = file1.read().splitlines()
        if lastname_info in verify and iden_info in verify and email_info in verify:
            print("it worked")
        else:
            print("user info incorrect")
else:
    print("user profile not found")
```

Comment: Totally embarrasing, but my else statement was saving to a typo of firstname_info, solved thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You are not writing the data from the GUI to any files.
Before reading from file which is **firstname_info** you should create it first.

you can modify your **register_user()** function as below code

```
def register_user():
    firstname_info = firstname.get()
    lastname_info = lastname.get()
    iden_info = iden.get()
    email_info = email.get()

    list_of_files = os.listdir()

    if firstname_info in list_of_files:
        file1 = open(firstname_info, "r")
        verify = file1.read().splitlines()
        if lastname_info in verify:
            if iden_info in verify:
                if email_info in verify:
                    print("it worked")
        else:
            print("user not found")
    else:
        file1 = open(firstname_info, "w")
        file1.write(lastname_info+"\n"+iden_info+"\n"+email_info)
        file1.close()
```